# Upgrade mariadb galera to 10.6

Tags: mariadb, galera

Anyone did maria db upgrade to 10.6 with galera cluster? I see this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mariadb-103-to-mariadb-104-with-galera-cluster/

but I am unable to find a document for upgrade to 10.6 with Galera. Wondering if its stable to do a 10.6 galera upgrade.

Thanks

Comment: This is essentially the same question you asked less than an hour ago (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212539/maridb-upgrade-from-10-3-to-10-6).

Comment: the question seemed to have closed . so edited to avoid asking references

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in Ubuntu plesk server: I want to upgrade Maridb 10.3 to 10.6.
I used the below steps and its working for me without any problem:

First, you need to take a backup of all your databases, so that you can restore them in case something goes wrong during the upgrade process. You can use the mysqldump command to take a backup of all databases.

**mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > backup.sql**

Next, you need to add the MariaDB repository to your server. You can do this by running the following command:

**sudo apt-get install software-properties-common**

**sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys 'https://mariadb.org mariadb_release_signing_key.asc'**

**sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] http://mirror.zol.co.zw/mariadb/repo/10.6/ubuntu bionic main'**

This command will add the MariaDB 10.6 repository to your server.

After adding the repository, update the package list by running the following command:

**sudo apt-get update**

Finally, you can upgrade to MariaDB 10.6 by running the following command:

**sudo apt-get install mariadb-server**

This command will upgrade the MariaDB server to version 10.6.

Once the upgrade is complete, you can check the version of MariaDB by running the following command:

**mysql -u root -p -e "SELECT VERSION()"**

This command will display the version of MariaDB.

If everything is working properly, you can restore the databases from the backup that you took in step 1 by running the following command:

**mysql -u root -p < backup.sql**

This command will restore all the databases.

**Note:** Please make sure to test your website and applications thoroughly after upgrading the MariaDB version to ensure that everything is working as expected.